# Java split string naming conventions

Tags: java, naming-conventions

If I split a String `permIp`, Is there a specific naming convention that is considered to be correct that I should follow for the String[] that I create, such as `permIps`, `permIpSplit` or `splitPermIp`? Or is this a matter of personal preference?

Comment: I would use `splitPermIp` or `permIpSplit`, but it's pretty much up to you.

Comment: belongs at programmer.stackexchange.com as it's about coding habits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`permIpSplit` seems fine. The naming convention should be `camel casing` and ensuring that it `conveys the correct meaning` to the people reading it apart from you. So including split in the variable name should do.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on what code style you have decided to go with. There is no set rule for naming conventions. There are lots of examples of different code styles but they are all just guidelines. A good place to start might be googles though.

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names

Answer (score 0):

There is no naming convention for the spiltted `String[]`  array. Use usual java naming convention for variable name which is suitable for array and also suitable for the original String which is being splitted.